# how to prevent UITextView to automatically enter newline if sentence has space at beginning

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I've got a UITextView that I want to give an inset on the first line. To do so, I insert a couple of spaces at the beginning. However, when the user enters too much text to fit onto one line, the entire text will move to the second line, leaving the entire first line blank.

(screenshots)

[image]
[image: http://cl.ly/image/373Z2g0y0P1Y]

The preferred way I'd want this is to only move 'f' to the next line, but probably because of the spaces that account for the first line indent, it recognizes the text after it as a word, and moves the entire thing to the next line.

I tried setting `self.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;` in the subclass of `UITextView` as well as `self.passwordTextView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;` in the ViewController, but no luck.

Comment: This behavior is as designed. You will likely have to make your own text view to get what you want. Why exactly do you need this behavior at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

Apperently the iOS sdk only responds to `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` when there are not whitespaces inside the string. So instead of adding whitespaces to account for the 'first line indent', I'm now using this in the `textViewDidChange:` method:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    self.passwordTextView.text = [self.passwordTextView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"\u00A0"]; 
}
```

Et voila!